# Does $ \|F'(t)\|_{\mathbb{R}^n}\leq G(t)$ imply that $F$ is lipschitz continuous

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $F:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ a continuously differentiable mapping, such that
$$ \|F'(t)\|_{\mathbb{R}^n}\leq G(t),$$
for all $t\in [0,1]$, where $G\in L^1([0,1],\mathbb{R}^+)$.

If $G=$ constante, we deduce that for all $s,t\in [0,1]$ one has
$$ \|F(s)-F(t)\|_{\mathbb{R}^n}\leq G|s-t|.$$

But can we deduce the same inequality, or an equivalent one, in the case where $G$ is time dependant?

Comment: Have you tried looking for a counterexample when $n=1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case for $s \le t$ in $[0,1]$:
$$
\|F(t)-F(s)\| =\|\int_s^t F'(\tau) d\tau\|\le \int_s^t \|F'(\tau)\| d\tau
\le \int_s^t G(\tau) d\tau
$$
and without more information on $G$ one wont't get more than that, I think.